# Having trouble removing characters from string in VB.net

Tags: string, vb.net

I'm using Excel Interop with VB.net. My problem is using string.Remove. I am trying to remove the last 3 characters from cells that always contain strings with 11 characters.

I have written some code to change the value of the cells in a range.

```
    Dim lastrow5 As Integer

    lastrow5 = xlWsheet2.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Dim myRange5, z As Excel.Range

    myRange5 = xlWsheet2.Range("E1:E" & lastrow5)

    For Each z In myRange5

        z.Value = z.Value.remove(8, 3)

    Next
```

But when I try to use Remove, I'm getting the error: 
`Object Reference not set to an instance of an Object`.

Can someone lead me in the right direction?

Comment: It depends on where the error is. It means z, value, xlWsheet2, UsedRange or Rows is null (Nothing). Just add checks for null.

Answer (score 0):

I think "the_lotus" is correct. Does this fix the error?

```
    Dim lastrow5 As Integer

    lastrow5 = xlWsheet2.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Dim myRange5, z As Excel.Range

    myRange5 = xlWsheet2.Range("E1:E" & lastrow5)

    For Each z In myRange5

        If cell.Value Is Not Nothing Then z.Value = z.Value.remove(8, 3)

    Next
```

Edit: Ed's solution (with formatting) was:

```
Dim lastrow5 As Integer lastrow5 = xlWsheet2.UsedRange.Rows.Count 
Dim myRange5, z As Excel.Range myRange5 = xlWsheet2.Range("E1:E" & lastrow5) 
For Each z In myRange5 
        If (z.Value Is Nothing) Then 
        ElseIf z.Value.ToString = "null" Then 
        Else z.Value = z.Value.ToString.Remove(8, 3) 
        End If 
Next
```

Comment: Yes! The root of the problem was that a few cells (out of hundreds) had nothing in them, so they needed to be weeded out using IF THEN ELSE. Here is the code that I came up with to address the empty cells: Dim lastrow5 As Integer
        lastrow5 = xlWsheet2.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        Dim myRange5, z As Excel.Range
        myRange5 = xlWsheet2.Range("E1:E" & lastrow5)
        For Each z In myRange5
            If (z.Value Is Nothing) Then
            ElseIf z.Value.ToString = "null" Then
            Else z.Value = z.Value.ToString.Remove(8, 3)
            End If
        Next